# What is the proper way to use React Memo with Flow?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

This line of code

```
export default memo(LoadingOverlay);
```

Gives flow error

```
Missing type annotation for `P`. `P` is a type parameter declared in  function type [1] and was implicitly instantiated at  call of `memo` [2].Flow(InferError)
```

And this line

```
export default memo<TProps>(LoadingOverlay);
```

Gives compile time error.
What's the proper use of `React memo` with `flow`?

EDIT:

Here is the full file example

```
// @flow

// React modules
import React, { memo } from 'react';

// Material UI components
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';

// Utils and defaults
import './checkbox.scss';

type TProps = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
  checked: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  onChange: Function;
};

/*
 * Presentational component with following props:
 *  value: String, value as a name of checkbox
 *  label: String, checkbox label
 *  checked: Boolean, checkbox state
 *  disabled: Boolean, checkbox availability state
 */
const Checkbox = (props: TProps) => {
  console.log('RENDER CHECKBOX');
  const {
    value,
    label,
    checked,
    disabled
  } = props;
  const { onChange } = props;

  return (
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          checked={checked}
          onChange={onChange(value)}
          value={value}
          disabled={disabled}
          color="primary"
        />
      }
      label={label}
    />
  );
};

Checkbox.defaultProps = {
  disabled: false,
};

export default memo<TProps>(Checkbox);
```

Comment: last one should be ok, what compile error you've got?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: TProps is not defined`
It seems babel doesn't strip this part.

Comment: Can you show how you defined `TProps`? Update the question

Comment: @Alex sure, you can take a look.

Comment: I've got this issue too. Seems @babel/preset-flow doesn't support this syntax yet >_>

Comment: Raised here: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9272

Comment: @fl0shizzle i didn't get anything from the issue, you have any news on this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have got the same problem. **The problem is not with the Flow but with Babel.**

## React.memo with Flow

You have got it right. Correct approach really is:

```
export default memo<Props>(MyComponent);
```

## Compilation problem

There are two ways to solve that.

### 1. Simple: Adding flow annotation to the top

Add `// @flow` to the top of the file. The error comes from Babel and it needs the annotation there. Even though you might have `all=true` in `.flowconfig` (and Flow work perfectly) you need to do that.

**Useful when using `create-react-app` and do not want to `eject`.**

### 2. Configuring Babel

Add Babel preset for Flow and specify `"all": true` option to your `.babelrc`:

```
{   
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-flow", {
      "all": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

**However, this needs anyone using `create-react-app` to `eject`.** (Or might use [react-app-rewired](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2976601/fl0shizzle) but I have no experience with that.)

This solution is mentioned on [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9272#issuecomment-451080388) (thanks @fl0shizzle for [mentioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863768/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-react-memo-with-flow#comment94871215_53863768) it) and for discussion about `create-react-app` solution look on [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6164).

Comment: So its more probably was caused by some version issues. As in new versions and projects everything seems to work ok.
Btw adding `//@flow` didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of flow. When I updated my flow version it just worked. I was missing the // @flow at the top so had to add all=true to my preset config.